# Convert date into "17. December 2015" Format

Tags: android, date, simpledateformat, android-date, android-dateutils

I am getting date in form of **"20150119"** and I want to convert it into the format like: **"19. January 2015"** .

How can I convert date in such format.

I tried below code:

```
private void convertDate() {
        String m_date = "20150119";
        SimpleDateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd");
        try {
            Date date = originalFormat.parse(m_date.toString());
            Log.e("Date is====", date.toLocaleString());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

But its giving me error:

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "20150119" (at offset 8)

Comment: SimpleDateFormat? `yyyyMMdd` to parse the date? What did you try to format ?

Comment: You getting a date in form of "20150119" but Your question is about an integer....is it really an integer or is it a string?

Comment: delete the points in Your simpleDateFormat like: "yyyMMdd"....

Comment: SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd") is wrong. SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd") is what you need

Comment: @Blackbelt I tried that also but i want in formate like `"19. January 2015"` .

Comment: it's a two steps process. The first step is to `parse` your String back to a `Date` object. The second is to `format` the `Date` to a String. To format it back use a different `SimpleDateFormat` object

Comment: @GrIsHu Where is your second simple date format in which you want your out put ???

Comment: @Blackbelt Can you explain by coding?

Comment: Use the first `SimpleDateFormat` to parse. Use  `SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd. MMMM yyyy");` to call format: `String output = formatter.format(date);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to specify two formats: one to parse your input, one to format your output.

1. The error occurs because the string you are trying to *parse* does not match the format you specified in `originalFormat`: that one needs to be

   ```
   SimpleDateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
   ```

   if you want to parse strings of the format `String m_date = "20150119";`. Parsing a string with that format will give you a `Date`:

   ```
   Date date = originalFormat.parse(m_date);
   ```
2. Then you may use another format to output your `Date`:

   ```
   SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd. MMMM yyyy");
   System.out.println("Date: " + outputFormat.format(date));
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `DateFormat`

```
SimpleDateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd");
```

So `SimpleDateFormat` expects a `String` like `"2015.01.19"` (note the dots).

You're supplying the `String`

```
String m_date = "20150119";
```

which does not contain the dots therefore `SimpleDateFormat` cannot parse the `String` as it does not contain dots (as specified by you).

To parse your `String` you have to use

```
SimpleDateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
```

To print the parsed date you have to use aother `SimpleDateFormat` e.g.

```
SimpleDateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd. MMMM yyyy");
```

Then you can use the method `format()` to format your date in the format you want.